# Replace one fragment with another, go back to previous fragment on toolbar back button press

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two fragments.

The first fragment has a `Button` view that, on click, should open the second fragment. The title of the toolbar should change between the two fragments (from "First Fragment" to "Second Fragment"). The second fragment should have a "back button" (arrow left icon) in the toolbar that, on click, lets the user go back to the first fragment.

How do I implement this?

Additionally, is it possible to animate the transition between the two fragments to make it appear as though the second fragment opens in a new "window" ([something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJdX0.gif))?

Here is my activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my first fragment class:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            //
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        Button openSecondFragmentButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.openSecondFragmentButton);
        openSecondFragmentButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.openSecondFragmentButton:
                // ?
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Here is my first fragment's layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/openSecondFragmentButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Open Second Fragment" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is my second fragment class:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    public SecondFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            //
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is my second fragment's layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I achieve the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addToBackStack` on the transaction to get the "back" behavior.

Use `setCustomAnimations` on the transaction to animate your fragment transitions.

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left)
                .commit();
```

To programmatically push the Back button:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Since you are apparently using the support library's `FragmentTransaction`, the animations should be the old `R.anim` kind of animations.  (The non-support `FragmentTransaction` uses the newer `R.animator` kind.)

/res/anim/slide_in_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

/res/anim/slide_in_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

/res/anim/slide_out_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />

</set>
```

/res/anim/slide_out_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Add this code to `onCreate` in the activity:

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then override `onOptionsItemSelected()`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
     }
```

Comment: Where does `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();` go?